# Flask Jinja2 - Parse JSON

Tags: python, json, flask, jinja2

I'm trying do display some JSON results in a Jinja2 HTML Template, but it returns either an empty page, or every character of the JSON on a new row, or every character with spacing.

The object that I'm sending to Jinja2 Template looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "John",
     "lastname": "Smith", 
     "age": 22, 
     "likes": [
       {"fruits": 
         ["bananas", "oranges"]
         }, 
       {"sweets": 
         ["chocolate"]
         }
       ]
     }
   ]
```

To send the JSON object to the Jinja2 template I use:

```
render_template("report.html", items=items)
```

On the Jinja2 Template HTML if I use `{{ items }}` it displays the full object as text.
If I'm trying to get the `{{ items['name'] }}` it will not display anything on the page, the page will be completely empty.

I have also tried

```
{% for x in items %}
{{ x }}
{% endfor %}
```

and it only displays the same "text" but with spacing:
`[ { " n a m e " : "J o h n " [...]`

In the HTML file, I'm trying to do something like:

```
<div id="name">{{ items['name'] }}</div>
```

How can I display the objects within the JSON object I'm passing to Jinja2?

Comment: When you say JSON... you mean python object?  Jinja2 renders python object to templates.

Comment: dictionary, yes...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think I got to the end of it.

I had to `json_dumps` the object at first, and then to `json.loads` the new object.

```
r = json.dumps(json_onject)
loaded_r = json.loads(r)
return render_template("report.html", items=loaded_r)
```

And now I can use any value from the JSON object.

Comment: After few hours of frustrations, this worked for me. Thanks. I wonder why is there a need to do it and why it is not explained elsewhere?

Answer (score 3):

I have a slightly modified example that worked really well for me:

app.py:

```
link_chart_data = {
    "type":
    "LinkChart",
    "items": [{
        "type": "node",
        "id": "ac1",
        "u": "static/icons/bank.png",
        "t": "45081063"
    }]
}

@app.route('/link_chart')
def covid():
    return render_template("link_chart/index.html", flask_data=link_chart_data)
```

Then in templates/link_chart/index.html:

```
<script>
    const parsedData = JSON.parse('{{ flask_data|tojson }}');
    const unparsedData = '{{ flask_data }}'
    console.log('parsed', parsedData)
    console.log('unparsed', unparsedData)
</script>
```

Which yields:

```
parsed, 
items: Array(1)
0:
id: "ac1"
t: "45081063"
type: "node"
u: "static/icons/bank.png"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
type: "LinkChart"
```

^^This is what I want. a new JSON object

and:

```
unparsed {&#39;type&#39;: &#39;LinkChart&#39;, &#39;items&#39;: [{&#39;type&#39;: &#39;node&#39;, &#39;id&#39;: &#39;ac1&#39;, &#39;u&#39;: &#39;static/icons/bank.png&#39;, &#39;t&#39;: &#39;45081063&#39;}]}
```

^^Which I really don't want.

The `|tojson` jinja template un-asciis the variable so that it gets passed as the same format it came from python (flask). the `JSON.parse()` javascript function is what converts it from a string to a JSON object in javascript.

I hope this helps.

Comment: thank you @Sharpie, it worked like a charm =)

Answer (score 2):

Hey so the json you have is an array not an object so you have to take that into consideration and access the object you want first and then access the attribute.

```
<div id="name">{{ items[0]['name'] }}</div>
```

or

In this case `x` becomes the object and you can use it like so:

```
{% for x in items %}
    <div id="name">{{ x['name'] }}</div>  
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. However, if I'm making an object `    items = dict()
    items['name'] = "John"
    return render_template("report.html", items=items)` and try to print items['name'] it still returns an empty page.

Answer (score 0):

I try JSON parse in Python with json.dumps but don't worked.
But, renamed the HTML file.

Of: `index.html`

From: `index.html.jinja`

and rename in Python app,

example: `return render_template('index.html.jinja', products=products)`

its worked!!