# HTML FLASK using {% for %} in JSON data

Tags: python, html, json, flask, nosql

I am using google firebase which returns data in JSON, compared to SQLAlchemy which returns it in something else.

In SQLAlchemy, I can fetch a database, pass it as a variable in flask render_template, and do something like this to display all the tables.

```
{% for Order in query %}
            <tr>
              <td>{{ Order.uuid }}</td>
              <td>{{ Order.costusd }}</td>
              <td>{{ Order.costcry }}</td>
              <td>{{ Order.orderinfo }}</td>
              <td>{{ Order.userpaid }}</td>
            </tr>
 {% endfor %}
```

If I attempt this with firebase/JSON data, it will display empty tables (the amount of tables that I have data in firebase) but with no data. I tried to do order['uuid']. etc for all of them, but that does not work either.

So, I am trying to display my database in the same way that SQLAlchemy can do it, but i am using a NOSQL database that is JSON.

Comment: Duplicate of [Flask Jinja2 - Parse JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50291923/flask-jinja2-parse-json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50291923/flask-jinja2-parse-json)

Working code to translate the NoSQL data into jinja2 readable:

```
r = json.dumps(json_onject)
loaded_r = json.loads(r)
return render_template("report.html", items=loaded_r)
```