# Parsing input onto template in Python Jinja like

Tags: python, json

Is there a possibility to parse JSON input to a Jinja-like template to extraxt some values?

E.g;

Input:

```
{"key":{"x":"y"}}
```

Template pseudocode:

```
{"key":{"x": {{value}} }}
```

to somehow extract the value. This is simple example, but I need to parse big JSON files and this might be a cleaner solution than hardcoding which param I want to access.

Comment: If you want to get the value _out_, why do you need a template? Just _parse_ the JSON, to actual dictionaries, and use e.g. `['key', 'x']` to represent the path to the value you want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flask Jinja2 - Parse JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50291923/flask-jinja2-parse-json)

Comment: I don't know how this pseudocode can be cleaner - it also need to hardcode params in this template.

Comment: there are modules to search in JSON using similart methods to XPATH for XML - [jsonpath-ng](https://pypi.org/project/jsonpath-ng/)